# Unix command to get list of directories over remote host

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, find, ls

I am trying to do ssh to a remote machine and get list of directory names present at pathA(/home/abc/mydata) which has any file that has been modified in last 1 hours.

Directory:-

```
/home/abc/mydata
    -> Directory a
        ->file1   last modified 1 hour back
        ->file2   last modified 1 year back
        ->file3   last modified 1 day back
    -> Directory b
        ->file11  last modified 1 year back
        ->file22  last modified 1 year back
        ->file33  last modified 1 year back
        ->Directory b1
          ->fileb1-11 last modified 1 hour back
    -> Directory c
        ->file111  last modified 1 year back
        ->file222  last modified 1 year back
        ->file333  last modified 1 year back
```

I am trying to get output as

```
   a  => as it has 1 file which was modified 1 hour back(file1)
   b  => as it has 1 file under sub directory of directory b (fileb1-11)
```

I am trying the following command

```
         ssh "host" -t "find /home/abc/mydata -type d  -mmin -60 -ls"
```

however I want the final output as

```
  a
  b
```

but this command lists the sub directories also as the output.

```
  a
  b
  b1
```

Some help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh "$host" '
find /home/abc/mydata -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d |
while read -r d; do
    [ "$(find "$d" -mmin -1 -type f -print -quit 2>/dev/null)" ] &&
    ls -ldi "$d"
done
'
```

Notes:

- With `mindepth`/`maxdepth`, the first `find` will look only at level 1.
- A separate `find` will look inside each subfolder for *regular files* (`-type f`) recently modified. If other recently modified file types (subdirectories/sockets/symlinks) should trigger the output, remove `-type f`.
- The `-t` parameter to `ssh` is only necessary if you want colorized `ls` output.
- The output of `ls -ldi ...` is slightly different from that of `find ... -ls`, but I'm guessing it will do.
- The return value of the second level `find` is too vague to use here. Instead, we simply test if its output is nonempty.

Comment: It lists all the directories present in depth 1 and not the ones that contain modified files based on time(-ctime or -mtime). Any fix for this?

Comment: I don't understand: in OP you said you wanted output `a` and `b`, not `a` and `b/b2`.

Comment: yes but your script is giving output as a,b,c and not a,b ie. All the directories under mydata folder are shown as output.

Comment: Hopefully fixed. `find` return value is too vague.

Comment: Thanks Matei. This looks to work the way I expected. However if I make this script as a single line statement and try to execute over shell it gives me error as "bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file". What am I missing ?

Comment: This got fixed with semicolon.!

Answer (score 1):

The original post appears to be nearly correct. Here's what worked for me (with Mac BSD):

```
ssh <user>@<host> -t "find /home/abc/mydata -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mmin -60 -type d"
```

- The mindepth arg is needed to avoid printing the source directory
  /home/abc/mydata.
- The maxdepth arg is needed so we don't print the    subdirectories
  below the first level.
- Eliminated the -ls arg    because it provides more details about
  the directories (e.g.    permissions), and may cause problems for
  extracting pathnames.

I would also recommend to anyone who needs a more sophisticated find to build it separately with variables to make debugging easier. Here's a script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=<username>
host=<hostname>
path=/home/abc/mydata
myfind="find ${path} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mmin -60 -type d"
ssh $user@$host -t $myfind
```